# SSDT, do I need different dacpacs if I need to deploy the same db to SQL Server 2008 and 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, deployment, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

While converting database project to SSDT and upgrading to SQL Server 2012 I need deployment script to work for both SQL Server 2008 and 2012.

I am using `sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish` to deploy the latest database bits.

In sqlproj project properties I do see a **target platform** dropdown with options 2005/2008/2012 sql server. Does it generate a different dacpac if I change this target platform? Do I need to carry two versions of dacpac for each sql server version?

Or will the same dacpac work for any version of sql server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes - different DACPACs for different SQL Server editions.  Bob Beuachemin wrote a useful [blog post](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/category/SQL-Server-2012.aspx) about DAC Fx3.0 vs. DAC 2.0

Answer (score 9):

I know this is 11 months old, but there is an option when you come to deployment specifically for this scenario - AllowIncompatiblePlatform.

```
//Set Deployment Options
DacDeployOptions dacOptions = new DacDeployOptions();
dacOptions.AllowIncompatiblePlatform = true;
```

Without setting the option I can deploy a 2008 dac to sql2012, but it will error if I deploy a 2012 dac to sql2008 with:

```
Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.DeploymentCompatibilityException: 
A project which specifies SQL Server 2012 as the target platform cannot be published to SQL Server 2008.
```

Setting the option means I do not get this error and can deploy to previous versions (back to 2005 I believe). NB You may also need to set the option TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings to true - YMMV.

Comment: I was able to deploy a SQL2012 dacpac to SQL2008R2 with just the `AllowIncompatiblePlatform = true;` option.

Answer (score 3):

From the command line using `SqlPackage.exe`, use the `p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform` option.  A warning will still be shown but it will continue.  This works from a SQL Server 2012 dacpac going to SQL Sever 2008 R2.

```
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish 
   /SourceFile:"testdb.dacpac" 
   /TargetDatabaseName:testDb 
   /p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform=true
   /TargetServerName:"testserver"
```